# Why does Blender think the bottom of my object is the Front?

Tags: 3d-view, axis

I can't make heads or tails out of what blender thinks is front/back left/right.  Top and bottom used to be no brainers along the z axis but now that's all screwy too.

I did View/Align View/Align View to Active/Front and it is showing me the underside of my object.

Every time I try another view it just gets worse, zooming me virtual miles from my work so I have to hunt around to find it.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Edit mode, "Align View to Active" will align your view to the active selection's LOCAL axes.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/navigate/align.html

Comment: Thank you!  I suspect that's one of those things I'd have learned if I'd come at blender in any sort of ordered fashion, classes, tutorials, etc rather than just jumping in.  Hopefully, I did the upvote thing correctly.  Thank you again!